# Cannot Use Required Unless Validator

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

In my application I am trying to use the required_unless validator but an error is thrown each time I hit the controller;

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequiredUnless,meta.app,pos does not exist.
```

This is the trace:

````
Message
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequiredUnless,meta.app,pos does not exist.
Level
ERROR
Exception
```{
   "class": "BadMethodCallException",
   "message": "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::validateRequiredUnless,meta.app,pos does not exist.",
   "code": 0,
   "file": "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Validation\/Validator.php:1146",
   "trace": [
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Validation\/Validator.php:365",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Validation\/Validator.php:268",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Validation\/Validator.php:293",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/app\/Http\/Controllers\/Shared\/CheckoutController.php:76",
       "{\"function\":\"checkout\",\"class\":\"App\\\\Http\\\\Controllers\\\\Shared\\\\CheckoutController\",\"type\":\"->\",\"args\":[\"[object] (Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Request)\"]}",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controller.php:54",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php:45",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php:212",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php:169",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php:665",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Pipeline.php:30",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Middleware\/SubstituteBindings.php:41",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php:151",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Pipeline.php:53",
       "\/var\/app\/current\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Middleware\/ThrottleRequests.php:57",
       "\/va…
````

This is my validation code:

```
$rules = [
            "client" => "required_unless,meta.app,pos",
            "customer" => "required",
            "customer.fullname" => "required|min:4",
            "customer.phone" => "required|numeric",
            "customer.email" => "email|required_unless,meta.app,pos",
            "payment" => "required",
            "payment.type" => "required",
            "items" => "required",
            "items.*.id" => "required",
            "items.*.quantity" => "required_if:meta.type,==,event|numeric",
            "items.*.seat" => "required_if:meta.type,==,food",
            "meta" => "required",
            "meta.type" => "required",
            "meta.timestamp" => "required",
            "meta.token" => "required_unless,meta.app,pos"
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, []);

        // Validate incoming request
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response($validator->errors(), 400);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `:` not `,` after `required_unless`.

`required_unless:anotherfield,value,`

Try `required_unless:meta.app,pos`

Comment: Thank you! Not really a typo for me since I thought I had done it the right way. my app works now. :D